# C++ class initializable from any sequence type

Tags: c++, iterator

I want a class that can be initialized from any sequence, that means from any type that has methods begin() and end() returning iterators.

```
template<typename B>
class A
{
public:
    A(any_sequence_type<B> arglist)
    {
        for(B b : arglist)
            init_members(b);
    }
}
```

I want the following to compile:

```
A<int> a = {1, 2, 3};
A<int> b = std::vector<int>();
A<Something> c = MyClassWithBeginAndEnd();
```

Is it possible?

EDIT:

Suggested solutions with template constructor don't work.
GCC says: template argument deduction/substitution failed: couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’.
Clang says: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'.

If I explicitly cast the initializer, things start to work, though.

```
A a = A({B(), B(), B()}); // does not work
A a = (std::initializer_list<B>){B(), B(), B()}; // works
```

Why is that?

Comment: Clang says: no known conversion from 'std::vector<B>' to 'std::initializer_list<B>'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With template constructor:

```
template<typename B>
class A
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    A(T&& arglist)
    {
        for (auto&& b : arglist) {
            init_members(b);
        }
    }

    // overload for initializer_list
    A(std::initializer_list<B> arglist) {
        for (auto&& b : arglist) {
            init_members(b);
        }  
    }

};
```

You got error if `T` doesn't provide `begin`/`end` and if content is not convertible to `B`.

You may use SFINAE to restrict allowed type `T` and so having error to call site instead of inside your constructor in case of misuse.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a52a7080cf7c775)

Comment: I thought of that, too. But that won't work for `A<int> a ({1, 2, 3});`

Comment: @mastov: You may create a specific overload for `std::initializer_list`. Edited and live Demo added.

Comment: Is there any reason why the template constructor doesn't accept initializer_list?

Comment: @haael initializer lists have no type

Comment: As Brian wrote: *This is because a braced-init-list is not an expression and does not have a type*.

Comment: OK, the version with template constructor and initializer_list accepts even raw arrays, so I guess it's the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need a template parameter for the type that `A::A` accepts. You should use SFINAE to disable this constructor if `Seq` is not a suitable sequence type; otherwise you will have issues with it winning overload resolution over the copy constructor.

```
template <typename Seq,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_convertible<decltype(*std::declval<Seq>().begin()), B>::value &&
            std::is_convertible<decltype(*std::declval<Seq>().end()), B>::value>>
A(Seq arglist) {
    for (B b : arglist) {
        init_members(b);
    }
}
```

Also consider using `const Seq&` instead of `Seq`, and `const B& b` or `auto&& b` instead of `B b`, to avoid potentially expensive copies.

If you want it to work with a *braced-init-list* too, you must add a *separate* `std::initializer_list` constructor. This is because a *braced-init-list* is **not an expression** and **does not have a type;** it is essentially always a special case.

Comment: Works in C++11 when I change enable_if_t to enable_if, but doesn't accept initializer_list.